# Passing and Viewing Combobox Text in VB

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a program with two forms: Form1 and FocusPRG. On the FocusPRG form I have two comboboxes set to List, one that let's you pick a Start Time and one that let's you pick a Stop Time for a process. Right now all I want to do is have Form1 look at the selected times and write them to a log file but the log file just shows blank lines and not any of the actual text. Here is the code on Form1 I am using:

```
Dim StartTime As String
Dim StopTime As String

StartTime = FocusPRG.StartTimePicker.SelectedText
StopTime = FocusPRG.StopTimePicker.SelectedText

WriteLog(StartTime)
WriteLog(StopTime)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I would bet on 'another one that falls in the Automatic Form Instance VB feature'. How do you open your FocusPRG form?

Comment: @Steve it is opened by pressing a button from within Form1. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: The action taken by the user is irrelevant.  It's the code that matters and that code could be executed by any user action or even a non-user action.

Answer (score 0):

The `SelectedText` property does not do what you think it does.  It's not the text of the selected value.  Just like in a `TextBox`, it's the text that the user has highlighted using either the mouse or keyboard.  If you want the text displayed in the control then you want the `Text` property, again, just like a `TextBox`.

Comment: I did try using the 'Text' property but got the same result.

Comment: In that case there is no item selected in the `ComboBox`.  If you can see an item selected in the `ComboBox` then you're looking at a different `ComboBox`, which means that the comment by Steve on your question is highly relevant.  He's asking for the specific code that displays the form, not the user action.

Comment: I have a default pre-defined in the `Form_Load` so I know there is a selection in the box.

Comment: Then that suggests that the `Load` event handler has not been executed, which is consistent with the default instance not having been displayed.  You need to be consistent, i.e. either use the default instance all the time or not at all.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I'll make some adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Dim StartTime As String
Dim StopTime As String

StartTime = FocusPRG.StartTimePicker.SelectedItem.ToString()
StopTime = FocusPRG.StopTimePicker.SelectedItem.ToString()

WriteLog(StartTime)
WriteLog(StopTime)
```

That is to say, use the [`SelectedItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the ComboBox instead of the [`SelectedText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

If you read the documentation of the two at MSDN, you can easily see the difference:

Definition of `SelectedText` says:

> Gets or sets the text that is selected in the editable portion of a ComboBox.

Definition of `SelectedItem` says:

> Gets or sets currently selected item in the ComboBox.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to use `SelectedItem.ToString`.  If the items are a type where that will produce the same result as what you see in the control then you can use the `Text` property to get the same result.  If the item type does not produce the same result as is displayed in the control, i.e. you must set the `DisplayMember`, then `SelectedItem.ToString` will actually give an incorrect result, e.g. if you bind a `DataTable` then it will give you "System.Data.DataRowView".

Comment: @jmcilhinney While that's true, using Text will yield what is in the `TextBox` part of the ComboBox. That means it will even yield any item typed into it, even if it is not in the items.

Comment: That is quite true but, if you have set the `DropDownStyle` to `DropDown` then it why would you not want that text entered by the user?  I think that, in this case, the `DropDownStyle` is almost certainly set to `DropDownList`, which makes your point moot.

Comment: I get an Unhandled Exception now that says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @jmcilhinney you are right, it is set to `DropDownList` so they have to chose and cannot write in their own text. I also have default choices pre-selected and defined in the `Form_Load` section. I tried `SelectedItem` without the `ToString()` and still received blank entries in the log. Adding the `ToString()` throws an Unhandled Exception error.

Comment: If that exception is a `NullReferebceException` then that is proof positive that no item is selected.  Everything is pointing to your having displayed an instance that you created yourself and then trying to get data from the default instance.  You need to settle on one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

FocusPRG must be an instance of the form, not just a class name. When creating FocusPRG, do something like:

```
dim FocusPRG1 as new FocusPRG
FocusPRG1.Show()
```

Also use `Text`, not `SelectedText` to get the user's input.

```
StartTime = FocusPRG1.StartTimePicker.Text
StopTime = FocusPRG1.StopTimePicker.Text
```

Also, the question is a little confusing because you say the controls are combo boxes but they are call xxxTimePicker, which suggests a different type of control.

Comment: I guess my naming schemes could use some improvement to avoid confusion in the future. Thanks

Comment: @TonyMcAwesome As far as naming, I've seen much worst. In this code I was assuming its a ComboBox.